# Como fazer query de uma coluna no banco e exibir filtrado em 3 colunas html?

Tags: query, select, while

bom dia.
Estou com uma dúvida no qual nunca me deparei antes com php e mysql.
Tenho a seguinte tabela exemplo no mysql:

```
ITEM     :   DEP   :    QTD
=============================
 1       :  T01    :   1000
 2       :  T02    :   2000
 3       :  T03    :   3000
 4       :  T01    :   4000
 5       :  T03    :   5000
=============================


    Tendo esta tabela acima no mysql, eu preciso exibir uma página com uma
 tabela HTML dessa maneira abaixo:


TABELA HTML PARA EXIBIR
================================
ITEM : T01   :  T02  :  T03 
 1   : 1000  :   0   :   0
 2   :  0    : 2000  :   0
 3   :  0    :   0   : 3000
 4   : 4000  :   0   :   0
 5   :  0    :   0   : 5000
================================
```

Explicando:
Preciso exibir uma query que me filtre em colunas separadas a qtd de cada depósito.

Pesquisei  e não sei como fazer isso, e nem que rumo tomar nas buscas. Tentei fazer um select para cada depósito e  while dentro de while e não consegui. Alguma forma de fazer isso?

Segue abaixo meu script, só que não faço idéia de como fazer isso, quem tiver uma idéia de como fazer, ou uma direção para eu pesquisar ficarei muito grato.

```
<?
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT item, dep, qtd FROM estoque  ");
?>

 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>                
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>T01</th>
            <th>T02</th>
            <th>T03</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
        <? while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><? echo $r['item']; ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <? } ?>

    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Pelo jeito você vai ter que fazer uma pivot table. Já tentou isso?

Comment: Pivot table, seria uma tabela auxiliar para este caso?

Comment: Eu achei algo como select case when then. Estou pesquisando sobre isso.

Comment: Você tem razão, pesquisando sobre pivot table, vejo que esse é o camilnho. Obrigado pela dica. Assim que eu aprender como se faz, eu posto aqui como ficou. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Eu uma vez tive um problema similar, eu resolveria seu problema da seguinte forma:

Caso algum item se repita na tabela estoque:
 - Criaria uma tabela listando todos os itens
 - Faria 2 selects da seguinte forma

```html
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>                
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>T01</th>
            <th>T02</th>
            <th>T03</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <? 
        $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT nome FROM itens");
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <? $busca = mysql_query ("SELECT qtd FROM estoque WHERE item = $r[0] and dep = 'T01'");
                    if($i = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){ 
                        echo $i[0];
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <? $busca = mysql_query ("SELECT qtd FROM estoque WHERE item = $r[0] and dep = 'T02'");
                    if($i = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){ 
                        echo $i[0];
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <? $busca = mysql_query ("SELECT qtd FROM estoque WHERE item = $r[0] and dep = 'T03'");
                    if($i = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){ 
                        echo $i[0];
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <? } ?>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Caso não se repita nenhum item na tabela estoque, faria da seguinte forma:

```html
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>                
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>T01</th>
            <th>T02</th>
            <th>T03</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <? 
        $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT item, dep, qtd FROM estoque");
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
            echo '<tr>';
                if($r[1] == 'T01') {
                    echo '<td>'.$r[2].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                } elseif(($r[1] == 'T02') {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$r[2].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                } else {
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                    echo '<td>0</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$r[2].'</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr>';
        } ?>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Vou tentar ajustar ao meu código esse script. Se der certo, posto aqui.Valeu